# Need to copy files from one location to another if path matches neglecting the root folder(s)

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to copy files from one location to another if path matches. In this scenario (pic attached), I have a folder C:\OldFiles\New Folder\ which contains Text.txt and I have another folder D:\NewFiles\New Folder\ which contains Text.txt. Notice that the root folder and the subfolder are different but the names of the file and its folder are exactly the same.

Developing a windows form C# tool which points to a path containing the new files which should replace the old ones in a different path. Help please? Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba8vf.png) to view my scenario.

Comment: My question is how do I perform this action.?

Comment: what do you mean by neglecting the root folders ?

Comment: the conditions to check only the name of the file and its parent folder and not C:\ or D:\ or its subfolders. "C:\OldFiles\"New Folder\ and "D:\NewFiles\"New Folder\ for example. @BchirMedAmine

Answer (score 0):

```
 string fileName = "test.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"C:\OldFiles\New Folder\";
            string targetPath =  @"D:\NewFiles\New Folder\ ";

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            // To copy a file to another location and 
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
            // Get the files in the source folder. (To recursively iterate through
            // all subfolders under the current directory, see
            // "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.")
            // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
            //       in this code example.
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //"Source path does not exist!
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            string sourcePath = @"C:\OldFiles\NewFolder";
            string targetPath = @"D:\NewFiles\NewFolder ";


            var a = sourcePath.Split('\\');
            var b = targetPath.Split('\\');
            string a1 = a[a.Length - 2]; //this will return OldFiles
            string a2 = a[a.Length-1]; //this will return NewFolder
            string b1 = b[b.Length - 2]; // this will return  NewFiles
            string b2 = b[b.Length-1]; // this will return NewFolder

            //you get the idea now use what ever you want with it in you if statement
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// pass true to replace existing if exists in destination 
File.Copy("source path here", "destination path here", true);
```